# JSPDF html() Method callback not Fired - PCF

Tags: typescript, jspdf, powerapps-component-framework

JSPDF html() method, Callback never gets fired nor able to Catch any Error. what could be the possible issue for callback not fire.

I also tried with plain html and js script via CDN. callback works perfectly from same Browser and PDF download Starts

```
import { IInputs, IOutputs } from "./generated/ManifestTypes";
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";

export class pcf implements ComponentFramework.StandardControl<IInputs, IOutputs> {
    private _value: number;

    private _notifyOutputChanged: () => void;
    // private labelElement: HTMLLabelElement;
    // private inputElement: HTMLInputElement;
    private container: HTMLDivElement;
    private _context: ComponentFramework.Context<IInputs>;
    private _refreshData: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject;
    private _edtorplaceholder: HTMLDivElement;
    private isrendered: boolean;
    //private editor : editorJS;


    public init(context: ComponentFramework.Context<IInputs>, notifyOutputChanged: () => void, state: ComponentFramework.Dictionary, container: HTMLDivElement): void {
        this._context = context;
        this.container = container;
        this._notifyOutputChanged = notifyOutputChanged;
        this._refreshData = this.refreshData.bind(this);
        //this._value = context.parameters.controlValue.raw!;


        const gridHTML = `
<div id="dashboard">

 <button id="save-button">Download</button>
 `
        let ele = document.createElement("div");
        this.container = document.createElement("div");
        this.container.id = 'GridContainer';
        this.container.innerHTML = gridHTML;

        //ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(new editorJS(), null), this.container);
        this.exportToPDF("");
        container.appendChild(this.container);
    }

    public refreshData(evt: Event): void {
        //  this._value = (this.inputElement.value as any) as number;
        //  this.labelElement.innerHTML = this.inputElement.value;
        this._notifyOutputChanged();
    }

    public updateView(context: ComponentFramework.Context<IInputs>): void {
        // storing the latest context from the control.
        //this._value = context.parameters.controlValue.raw!;
        this._context = context;
        var params = context.parameters;


        if (params.fileName.raw?.startsWith('yes') && (this.isrendered !== true)) {
            console.log("pcf fired");
            this.isrendered = true;
            return;


        }
    }


    public getOutputs(): IOutputs {
        return {
            //controlValue: this._value
        };
    }
    public pdfReady(doc: any): void {

    }
    public destroy(): void {
        //  this.inputElement.removeEventListener("input", this._refreshData);
    }

    public delay(ms: number) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    public exportToPDF(data: string) {
        try {
            //window["html2canvas"] = html2canvas;
            const doc = new jsPDF();
            var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
            var height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
            doc.setFontSize(40);
            doc.text("Sample Header", 10, 10);
            doc.line(width / 4, height / 4, width, height / 4);
            console.log("html method called!");
            doc.html(`<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <body>
            <h2>Text input fields</h2>
            <p>Note that the form itself is not visible.</p>
            <p>Also note that the default width of text input fields is 20 characters.</p>
            </body>
            </html>
            `, {
                callback: (doc) => {
                    console.log("html is getting Called Back..!");
                    doc.save();
                }
            }

            );
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

}
```

package.json

---

{
"name": "pcf-project",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Project containing your PowerApps Component Framework (PCF) control.",
"scripts": {
"build": "pcf-scripts build",
"clean": "pcf-scripts clean",
"rebuild": "pcf-scripts rebuild",
"start": "pcf-scripts start",
"refreshTypes": "pcf-scripts refreshTypes"
},
"dependencies": {
"@types/react": "^17.0.38",
"@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
"clean": "^4.0.2",
"html2canvas": "1.0.0-rc.1",
"jspdf": "^2.5.1",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@types/node": "^16.4",
"@types/powerapps-component-framework": "^1.3.0",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.0",
"eslint": "^7.32.0",
"eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.2",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
"eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
"pcf-scripts": "^1",
"pcf-start": "^1",
"typescript": "^4.3"
}
}

---

Comment: I don't think the problem is in your code, I tried using `jspdf` in fresh project `powerapps component framework` and it didn't work too. `html()` never resolves the Promise

Answer (score 1):

jsPDF callback never gets fired because it depends on core-js to handle Promise.

If you import 'core-js/features/promise' callback is called but it breaks powerapss because powerapps uses bluebird to handle Promise

I make it work using

```
import jsPDF from "jspdf/dist/jspdf.es.min";
const myPromise = global.Promise;
var pp = require('core-js/features/promise');

Object.defineProperty(global, 'Promise', {
    value: myPromise
});
```

And then when generating pdf

```
public generatePdf() {

    const element = document.getElementById("input-html2pdf") as HTMLInputElement;
    Object.defineProperty(global, 'Promise', {
        value: pp
    });

    const doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4", true);

    try {
        doc.html(element.value, {
            html2canvas: {
                allowTaint: true,
                useCORS: true,
            },
            callback: async (doc) => {
                doc.save(`doc.pdf`);
                Object.defineProperty(global, 'Promise', {
                    value: myPromise
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Using this aprox works witch npm build watch and imported to powerapps as code component.

Comment: Thanks. Same issue as mermath not able to save the app after adding pcf into canvas app

Answer (score 0):

I just realized Microsoft has implemented this functionality.
You can enalbe [PDF function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-pdf) in experimental options.

It is not exactly the same buy you can create an Screen with html Text and just use this function

Comment: PDF function wont work for 10s of Pages of PDF with a lot of Graphics like, Images, Tables with CSS, Formatting layout etc..,,

Comment: No. Not for that case. And sometimes break lines at the end of the page